# Important elements of web page are "nvisible"

Tags: seo

I ran my website through a web tool that evaluates SEO weight of elements and in the report it says that certain parts, like Description and other meta tags are missing... Also as a thumbnail of my site it shows a default server page. At the same time it shows the list of other pages that are linked from index page.

I checked and this AGENT is not blocked in robots.txt

Now, how can that be?

[Demo](http://www.woorank.com/en/www/usabilitest.com)

Comment: That tool may not be any good.

Comment: But it's not just showing random data. It does see the server screen. I am not even sure how it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the description issue is caused by the the fact that you are using "META" instead of "meta" in your meta tags.

Comment: Are you saying that HTML tags are case-sensitive?

Comment: I have not said that. I just said that MAYBE the parser of that tool recognise just the meta-tag lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

there are many sites out that can run similar tests on your site such as the one you provided. It is just that site showing old data, you may want to submit your sitemap.xml to Bing & Google Webmaster Tools. If your site doesn't have a sitemap.xml file you may want to consider creating one.